# Installing python development package on RHEL

Tags: python, rhel

I have been trying to install python development package on my red hat machine but not able to find the package any where.

My server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)( x86_64 GNU/Linux) with python 2.6.6 on-board

I have tried doing a "yum install python-devel" but have not been successful.

From where can i grab hold of this package? Any external link available?

Comment: `python-devel` is the correct package name. Is your subscription registered properly?

Comment: yes that is the correct package name and there is no issue with subscription. i have installed few other modules with out any issues. But not able to find the development package for python

Comment: What's the output? What's the related config if you edited it? What are we supposed to work with?!

Comment: And, it's off topic as a system administration rather than programming question, [sf] is for those (do read [their How To Ask](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

You can search the repositories available to you using the `yum search xxxxx` command, where xxxxx is the name or part of the name of the package you are looking for. This will show you what is available in the repositories you currently have installed/enabled. If its not there you first will need to install the repo. Then use `sudo yum install python-devel` or a specific version.

Or install it manually

`wget` the last version from [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/), unzip it, prepare the compilation and `make` the build. Finally `make install` it.